# RouteParam not being passed from RouterLink *Updated*

Tags: angular

I have a simple application with two components and a service. Ill outline the application flow as I post each part of the application.

**api.service - this service contains two api calls and holds one variable (id) Im sharing between my components and will be valued from the menu links.**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  url = 'api address';

  id;  //variable being shared

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getMenus(){
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }
  getContent(){
    return this.http.get(this.url);
}
}
```

**nav.component.ts - this component holds the navigation for the site, which is a list of iterated items from one of the API calls:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

menus; //holder for iterable
id; // shared variable

  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getMenus().subscribe(res => {this.menus = res});
  }
  set_id(id){
    this.api.id = this.id
 }
}
```

}

**view for nav.component - each menu is linked to the content route and Im passing the index of each item to the link as an id, which is also the shared variable.**

```
<div *ngFor="let menu of menus; index as id">
    <ul>
        <li><a routerLink ="content/{{id}}" (click)="set_id(id)">{{menu['course-lesson-name']}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

content.component.ts - this component holds content from the second API call and uses the shared id variable to select content from the call.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';
import { switchMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.css']
})
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {
content; //holder for iterable
id; //from api.service
  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.api.getContent().subscribe((res : any[]) => {
    this.content = res[this.api.id]}) //this is supposed to be the shared variable being valued from nav.component
  }
  }
```

view for content.component

```
<p *ngIf="content">{{content['course-lesson-name']}}</p>
```

here is my router:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ContentComponent } from './content/content.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'content/:id', component: ContentComponent},
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Users should be able to click on a menu item and have the index of that item be passed to the shared variable (id) which is passed to the router and into content from the route param. The links are being formed correctly, but no content is being displayed when I click on any of the links.

Comment: where is the logic to store the `id` of the clicked item?

Comment: Your content is guarded by an `ngIf` directive. What happens if you put a hello world h1 in there? Still empty?

Comment: Also @Aravind has a strong point.

You're using the iterator to generate identifiers with `<div *ngFor="let menu of menus; index as id">` but you never store these values anywhere. The ApiService never has its `id` variable assigned.

Comment: Code has been updated with a function for assigning the value - still no content working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look on how to retrieve route parameters in the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/router).

In short your controller would need to load the [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) service and subscribe to its `params` observable to get the route params:

```
(...)
    constructor(private api: ApiService, route: ActivatedRoute) { }
(...)

    ngOnInit(){
      this.route.params.subscribe(params => { this.id = params.id })
(...)
```

Comment: Would this also need to be in the service? Ive been looking for something like this as Ive built the same app already in AngularJS and used $routeParams to handle this. Thanks

Comment: good news - its working, but only one a single link; the first one. After that, the content will not change as required when the other links are clicked.